# How to open the Date/Time settings on Windows Phone 8 programmatically?

Tags: datetime, windows-phone-8

The app I'm working on relies on the correct date/time being set for synchronization purposes.  Apparently you cannot programmatically set the date and time on the phone.  Is there a way though to open the Date/Time settings programmatically?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you want to do with the "date/time" settings?

Comment: I want to open the Date+Time settings so that the user can manually correct the date and time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Lancher class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.launcher.launchuriasync.aspx) to navigate to various settings, but there's **NO** option to open the date time selection.

Here's the available uri schemes for settings:

```
Launch Airplane Mode Settings Page: ms-settings-airplanemode:
Launch Bluetooth Settings Page: ms-settings-bluetooth:
Launch Cellular Settings Page: ms-settings-cellular:
Launch Wi-Fi Settings Page: ms-settings-wifi:
Launch Location Settings Page: ms-settings-location:
Launch Account Settings Page: ms-settings-accounts:
Launch Email Account Settings Page: ms-settings-emailandaccounts:
Launch Lock Screen Settings Page: ms-settings-lock:
```

[All available Uri Scemes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662937%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Whats with the downvote? That's the answer. There's NO way to do what it's been asked.

Comment: The downvote was because you added no information, and you edited your answer AFTER you were downvoted (remember, there is a record of this...).  It was equivalent to saying "you can use a bicycle pump to inflate a tire, but not to do what you want".  It's not useful to me that I can't use X to do Y.  I want to know what I CAN use to accomplish the task.  There's a big difference between saying "You cannot use X to do Y" and "You cannot do Y at all".

Comment: Seriously? The edit was making bold the NO option. The information was already there.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for clearing that up. I don't think you can do this the way you want to.

[From this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/5a640f18-3663-4283-87a9-0819e876aa79/set-devices-date-and-time-programaticallywindows-phone?forum=wpdevelop):

> At best you can get the difference between the user's clock and the clock on the system to which the program is talking. Of course the user's clock is subject to change. I don't think that people change their clock's time very frequently, but it is still something to be considered.

You can launch some settings programatically like this:

```
Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(“ms-settings-bluetooth:”));
```

But date/time is not one of them. [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662937%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) is a link to available settings