# Navigating to date time settings screen from my Windows Phone Application

Tags: datetime, windows-phone-8, navigation

I want to modify the system time in windows phone if it doesn't matches my server time,
so for that i want to prompt the user to change their date time by redirecting them to date time settings screen.

this is the code which i have used for android

new Intent(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionDateSettings);

suggest me a way to do the same in Windows phone.

Comment: [Similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23760904/2681948) was already asked before.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll be able to access the date and time from the settings panel thought you could access the settings page from the application.

```
ConnectionSettingsTask connectionSettingsTask = new ConnectionSettingsTask();
connectionSettingsTask.ConnectionSettingsType = ConnectionSettingsType.WiFi;
connectionSettingsTask.Show();
```

Have a look at these: [How to link to a specific system-setting in your Windows Phone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12772374/)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662937(v=vs.105).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394011(v=vs.105).aspx

Hope it helps!